# Azure Purview - JSON properties in ADLSGen2 store are getting messed up

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-purview

I have a ADLS Gen2 lake. In the lake I have a taxonomy.

/environment/source/system/entity/myspecificfilenameconvention/*.json

Purview seems to pick up my paths and conventions just fine, however it is munging a simple JSON file format and giving this in the UI!

[image]

The file format is pretty straight forward as below. Any idea why Purview is making a dogs breakfast of it?

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "MyType",
            "url": "/path"
        },
        "Id": "11111",
        "IsDeleted": false,
        "AccountId": "222222",
        "CreatedById": "333333",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-10-26T08:43:04.000+0000",
        "Field": "created",
        "OldValue": null,
        "NewValue": null
    }, ...
```

Comment: Save your file as UTF-8, not UTF-16

Comment: Thanks @HongOoi but I have 100s of GB of the stuff. Tens of thousands of files.

Comment: Write a program to do the conversion

Comment: Thanks - we are coming up with a plan, the data flows in to the lake hourly on a schedule so we need to think it through a bit.

Comment: Ideally, change your source to generate UTF-8 output, JSON is defined to be UTF-8 so it's noncompliant right now

Comment: The format is indeed the issue - can you add as an answer and I will accept - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Hong Ooi comment. Just post an answer to end this question:

"Save your file as UTF-8, not UTF-16" did the trick.